# Is the expression "specifically tailored" redundant?

Tags: redundancy

I guess the title pretty much covers it, but I'd like to complete the sentence just in case:

"The literature seems to lack a treatment **specifically tailored** to such method"

Comment: A suit may be tailored to fit a person, or it may be *specifically tailored* for the person to wear to the Grand Ball.

Comment: No I don’t think it’s “redundant” in that it seems to be in constant but infrequent use figuratively. For example, “The ABC has released some clips from their program *You Can't Ask That* that have been specifically tailored for the classroom.”

Comment: Even if redundant it adds emphasis.

Comment: I like the example given by user @HotLicks as an instance where "specifically tailored" is not redundant. But I guess it could gain from a more general argument. Nonetheless, it counts as an answer to my question... I would mark it as answered, but I can't find a button or whatever gets it done. I'm sorry hahahah I on my phone so I'm gonna blame poor UI on this